# Flutter show space when array is null [] and style doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

In my screen data[index]['text'] show [] when don't have a value, but style doesn't work
how do I show space instead of [] when it doesn't exist?

```dart
return ListTile(
     title: Html(data: """<br> """ + data[index]['id'] + ' - ' + data[index]['value'] + ' - ' + """ <span style="color: red"> """ + (data[index]['text']) + """ </b> """ + """ """),
     trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
     onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/approve', arguments:
 data[index]['id'].toString()),
     isThreeLine: false,
     dense: true,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about

1) [null-aware operators](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators) (alternative expression if null, a.k.a. short-hand for ternary operator)

2) [string interpolation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings) (to avoid long concatenations)

Solution:

```
return ListTile(
  title: Html(
    data: "<br/> ${data[index]['id']} - ${data[index]['value']} - <b>${data[index]['text'] ?? "&nbsp;"}</b>"
  ),
  trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
  onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/approve', arguments:
 data[index]['id'].toString()),
  isThreeLine: false,
  dense: true,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
return ListTile(
    title: Html(data: """<br> """ + data[index]['id'] + ' - ' + data[index]['value'] + ' - ' + """ <b> """ + (data[index]['text'] != null ? data[index]['text'] : " " )  + """ </b> """ + """ """),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
    onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/approve', arguments:
    data[index]['id'].toString()),
    isThreeLine: false,
    dense: true,
);
```